# How to read property of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects, react-context

***Hello!***

I'm using React with React Context API. I have `App.js` component with whole app. It is functional component. In it' there is state (`useState`) for context:

```
const [contextValue, setContextValue] = useState(null)
```

And `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const wrapper = async () => {
      let data = {};

      const fetchData = () => {
        fetchAbout().then((res) => (data.about = res.data));
        fetchNews().then((res) => (data.news = res.data));
        fetchArticles().then((res) => (data.articles = res.data));
        fetchOffer().then((res) => (data.offer = res.data));
        fetchPortfolio().then((res) => (data.portfolio = res.data));
        fetchQuestions().then((res) => (data.questions = res.data));
      };
      await fetchData();

      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.about);

      setContextValue(data);
    };

    wrapper();
  }, []);
```

---

So in `fetchData` function I'm creating properties of `data` object.
So after `await fetchData()`, there are 2 console logs. And as expected, first is logging data objects with its fields:

[image: data object with it's fields]

---

But there are problem with `console.log(data.about);`, because it is logging `undefined`!.
I expected, that it'll be value of about field in data object (like in first `console.log`)

***Thanks in advance***

Comment: Try changing fetchAbout().then((res) => (data.about = res.data.about));

Comment: Your `fetchData` returns `undefined`. You aren't waiting for any of the Promises inside to resolve. Use `Promise.all` to wait for each Promise to resolve first, then call `setContextValue`. `Promise.all([fetchAbout(), fetchNews()]).then((res) => setContextValue({ about: res[0].data, news: res[1].data ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetchData isn't returning a promise, so you can't "await" for it.
by the time you `console.log(data.about)` the data is not yet populated.
you could solve it by

```
  const fetchData = () => {
    return Promise.all([
       fetchAbout().then((res) => (data.about = res.data)),
       fetchNews().then((res) => (data.news = res.data)),
       fetchArticles().then((res) => (data.articles = res.data)),
       fetchOffer().then((res) => (data.offer = res.data)),
       fetchPortfolio().then((res) => (data.portfolio = res.data)),
       fetchQuestions().then((res) => (data.questions = res.data)),
    ])
  };
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it solved my problem. Can you explain, how does `Promise.all()` work?

Comment: promise.all gets an array of promises and returns a promise which resolves after all promises have resolved (if one or more failed it will reject)